# Build configuration is always adding debug symbols

Tags: qt5, qmake

I used to run my application on Qt 5.10.0 and I don't remember facing this issue, I do release build and I get the binary without symbols. I downgraded to 5.9.2 with qt creator 4.1 because it is the standard version that comes with CentOS 7 repo so I'll be able to deploy my application as a standard RPM.

With 5.9.2 I choose release build and I still get the huge sized binary, the `Makefile` is generated with `CFLAGS` including `-g`, but If I remove it manually I get the binary without debug symbols. Same thing happens when I do for example `qmake CONFIG+=release`. Is there some sort of default settings I should override?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by chance. Apparently the `qmake` spec file

`/usr/lib64/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf`

contained a line saying `QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -O2 -g ....`, it seems this was overriding the default `CFLAGS`, I removed the line and `qmake` start the correct build configuration. For some reason, the previous debug build was giving a 220 MB binary while now the debug build gives a 66 MB binary.